# random pink square apeared in the tile pallete

Tags: unity-game-engine

a pink square suddenly appeared in tile palette, covering up half of my sprites,  it is not a sprite, it appears when I try to place one of my sprites in the tile map, most sprites work, its just this one, when I select the image one pops up next to the name

Comment: Well click through your hierarchy  till you find out what it is?

Comment: It is a case of missing material.

Comment: Hasnain Shaukat is right.